# How to build an efficient and flexible security layer for a private project host

Tags: linux, security, system-administration

I have a dedicated server running Linux.
The operating system runs the following -let's call them- **components**:

- **PostgreSQL**

  - **Access rule**: Only staff (and local access of course)
- **Apache**

  - **Sites**

    - Public site: Every one
    - Private site: **Only** staff

The staff reaches these components via WAN, and I'd like to know which is the best, easiest, and most flexible way to apply these Access rules (also centralized so I don't have to configure **every** component).
Of course the server will run much more stuff, but I think I'll manage when I'll have a solution for the above.

I thought about some ways though:

- VPN: Which won't work as I have a public thing that has to be available to the world, and it seems a bit complicated to me either... I don't know
- LDAP auth: This seem to be the best, but I only the definition of LDAP

What are your guesses guys?

Would you recommend any good readme to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VPN is your best solution. It is widely used in exactly the same scenario - Postgre and the private site are on 192.168.x.x addresses (you can configure this using virtual interfaces, e.g. eth0:0 and then tell them to listen only on this interface), the public site is on a real public IP address. When the staff connects via VPN, they also get a 192.168 IP address and have authenticated and encrypted access to all internal components - otherwise, only the public site can be accessed. If you can afford additional resources, the best solution is a de-militarized zone (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29). There are other solutions, but none that work with Windows clients out-of-the-box.

Comment: http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/howto1.html or http://pigtail.net/nicholas/pptp/ whereby I recommend the latter. Please accept my answer if it helped :)